# Не могу подключиться к github по ssh

Tags: github, ssh

Система Arch Linux оболочка xfce.

```
[sergey@sergeyM ~]$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/sergey/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/sergey/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [192.30.253.123] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.github.com:443 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host '[ssh.github.com]:443' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sergey/.ssh/known_hosts:3
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[192.30.253.123]:443' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sergey/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sergey/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sergey/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Содержимое директории **~/.ssh**

```
[sergey@sergeyM ~]$ ls -al ~/.ssh
итого 24 
drwx------  2 sergey users 4096 июн 20 15:58 . 
drwx------ 24 sergey users 4096 июн 20 15:33 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    53 июн 20 15:58 config 
-rw-------  1 sergey users 1679 июн 20 15:33 id_rsa.sergeyM88 
-rw-r--r--  1 sergey users  401 июн 20 15:33 id_rsa.sergeyM88.pub 
-rw-r--r--  1 sergey users 1628 июн 20 16:02 known_hosts
```

Comment: Вы ключ-то в настройках аккаунта добавили?

Comment: https://fotki.yandex.ru/next/users/mageston/album/541443/view/1536189

Comment: Конечно добавил, на digital ocean все работает, а тут почему-то никак.

Comment: Где у вас ключ находится? Судя по выводу, SSH вообще ни одного кандидата не нашел.

Comment: Ключ находится: /home/sergey/.ssh/
И приватный и публичный.

    [sergey@sergeyM ~]$ ls -al ~/.ssh
    итого 24
    drwx------  2 sergey users 4096 июн 20 15:58 .
    drwx------ 24 sergey users 4096 июн 20 15:33 ..
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root    53 июн 20 15:58 config
    -rw-------  1 sergey users 1679 июн 20 15:33 
    id_rsa.sergeyM88
    -rw-r--r--  1 sergey users  401 июн 20 15:33 
    id_rsa.sergeyM88.pub
    -rw-r--r--  1 sergey users 1628 июн 20 16:02 known_hosts

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: попробуйте явно указать ключ используя `-i`

Comment: Обычно публичные ключи находятся в id_rsa.pub, в другие не будет просто так смотреть. Михаил правильно написал по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в config

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.sergeyM88
```

И незабудьте добавить этот ключ на github